# Intuition on the fiber (preimage) of $f$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve a problem that wants me to show that an equivalence relation $x\sim_f y$ if $f(x) = f(y)$ where $f: X \rightarrow Y$ has an equivalence class of $[x] = f^{-1}(f(x))$ Where $f^{-1}$ is defined as the *preimage* or *fiber* of $f$.

---

I just want some clarification on the exact definition of this. Given my current understanding of the term preimage I have tentatively defined $f^{-1}(f(x))$ to be:

- $f^{-1}(f(x)) = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) \in Y \}$

This comes from my understanding of the general definition of preimage, which, given two sets $A$ and $B$ and a function which maps points in $A$ to points in $B$, $\sigma : A \rightarrow B$ the preimage of a subset $D \subset B$ is defined as:

- $\sigma^{-1}(D) = \{a \in A \mid \sigma(a) \in B \} \subset A$
  Furthermore the fiber is the special case when $D$ is a singleton $\{b\}$

---

Given this, am I on the right tract in understanding the fiber of $f$ to be the set of all values in the domain which $f$ carries into the image? Or is there some subtlety I'm missing? As I'm looking at it a little more, it seems like a pretty straightforward substitution with $f(x)$ taking the place of $b$ in the general definition.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions you've given make no mention of the subset your taking the preimage of, and they will always give you the whole domain! The definition of a preimage of $D$ should be $$\sigma^{-1}(D)=\{a\in A \;|\; \sigma(a)\in D\},$$
which in English is "the set of all domain elements that $f$ sends to $D$". If $D=\{b\}$ is a singleton, we have
$$\sigma^{-1}(b)=\{a\in A \;|\; \sigma(a)=b\}.$$

Also, we typically talk of the *fibers* of $\sigma$ with a single *fiber* being $\sigma^{-1}(b)$ for some $b\in B$.